# gerrit -application error server error connection refused

Tags: email, smtp, gerrit

```
In gerrit,While registering with a open id(gmail) for the first time it got registered  no issues ,but when I add another user with a open id(gmail)  [settings->Contact Information->Register New Email] am getting an error like this,  
        Application error
        Server error
        Connection refused
        What kind of problem is it.My config file
        [sendemail]
            enable = true
            smtpUser = *xxxxx*@gmail.com
            smtpPass = "xxxx"
            smtpServerPort = 25
            smtpServer = 127.0.0.1
            smtpEncryption = none
            sslVerify = true
            from = MIXED***
```

My error log goes like this

```
        com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.account.AccountSecurityImpl : Cannot send email verification message to %$%$#@@gmail.com
        com.google.gerrit.server.mail.EmailException: Connection refused
            at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.SmtpEmailSender.open(SmtpEmailSender.java:245)
            at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.SmtpEmailSender.send(SmtpEmailSender.java:152)
            at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.OutgoingEmail.send(OutgoingEmail.java:116)
            at com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.account.AccountSecurityImpl.registerEmail(AccountSecurityImpl.java:311)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
            at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.MethodHandle.invoke(MethodHandle.java:91)
            at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.JsonServlet.doService(JsonServlet.java:382)
            at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.JsonServlet.service(JsonServlet.java:268)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:216)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:141)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:93)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:63)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:129)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestCleanupFilter.doFilter(RequestCleanupFilter.java:54)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:129)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:122)
            at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:110)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:921)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:59)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1069)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
            at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:163)
            at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:184)
            at com.google.gerrit.server.mail.SmtpEmailSender.open(SmtpEmailSender.java:215)*/
            ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using your localhost as smtpServer ? It looks like your localhost does not support what you're doing. If you have a GMail account, just use Google smtp.

We use the following config and it works just fine:

```
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
        smtpUser = XXX@gmail.com
        smtpEncryption = ssl
        smtpPass = XXXXX
```